# material-ui and react does not reproduce same behavior after `npm run build`?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, babeljs, create-react-app

I am working on creating a content-library, where I am using react-app  using `create-react-app`. The `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^2.0.1",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
    "react-katex": "^2.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

When running `yarn install && yarn start` the application comes out fine, see the snapshot below

While when I ran `yarn build && serve -s build` or `npm run build && serve -s build` , the application does not look the same and UX is messed up, see below

The `yarn.lock` file is linked https://pastebin.com/dDHnvRWA

### Expected Behavior

The page on `yarn start` and one after running `npm run build && serve -s build` should exactly be the same

### Current Behavior

The page that comes up after `npm run build && serve -s build` are different (see snapshots attached)

### Your Environment

```
| Tech         | Version |
|--------------|---------|
| Material-UI/core  | ^1.4.1 |
| Material-UI/icons | ^2.0.1|  
| React        |    ^16.4.1     |
| Browser      |   Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)      |
| TypeScript   |      None   |
| etc.         |         |
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was created because the Material React Components were imported from incorrect path

**Incorrect Path (causing the issue)**

```
import {AppBar, Toolbar, Typography} from
    "@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min";
```

**Correct Path**

```
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
```

After importing from **Correct Path**, the application started to behave as expected

Comment: I need to wait for 22 hours for this

Comment: I think you can by now.